# Unnecessary folders from NuGet packages

Tags: c#, nuget-package

My c# app target framework is 4.6.2

[image]

I downloaded from NuGet some packages, my question:

when I open my app in file explorer, under packages\somepackage\lib I have this:

[image]

do I really need net 40 and net45 folders?

can I delete that? how do I know what is unnecessary?

Comment: This is normal, and nothing to be concerned about

Comment: Why do you want to remove those directories? They're packages from which the appropriate resources will be referenced and copied to your output directory, there's no need to clean those up manually.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvoted without comment, as it was a legitimate question and asked in a fairly well formatted way

Comment: Because I have a lot of packages and I want to cut some weight

Comment: If you never need those version yes you can safely delete them if you wanted

Comment: `Because I have a lot of packages and I want to cut some weight` Why is it a concern? Are you running low on disk space? Are you committing them into source control and worried about that? Something else?

Comment: 1st, this is too broad, because you don't point **why** you need to remove this folders. 2nd, your question is not showing any search attempts about this (or about nuget folder structure). 3rd, it will depend on personal point of view, so this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reason why NuGet keep the folders

Nuget uses two different methods to manage packages of every project:

1. packages.config
2. PackageReference

`packages.config` is only used for old project files which cannot import and reference NuGet packages automatically. NuGet will change the *.csproj file to add the references. Because it changes the code which is under version control and cannot use an absolute path, so it should put the NuGet package cache folders in every solution. In this case, NuGet might have the ability to remove the useless folders. **But** this is the behavior of legacy NuGet version (version 2.x). NuGet doesn't want to fix a legacy behavior.

`PackageReference` is the new behavior of NuGet references. NuGet put all the NuGet cache in a common folder so that it will not take too much disk space by the same NuGet packages. In this case, NuGet doesn't know every lib version on your whole computer projects, so it can't remove the *useless* version folders.

**Conclusion：** NuGet doesn't know whether it is safe to remove them in `PacakgeReference` and doesn't want to remove them in `packages.config`.

#### Upgrade `packages.config` to `PackageReference`

---

UPDATE:
From VisualStudio 2017 version 15.7 there is an integrated feature that allows you to do this upgrade without using third party tools [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

In Solution Explorer, right-click on the References node or the packages.config file and select Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...

---

You can try a Visual Studio extension [NuGet PackageReference Upgrader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CloudNimble.NuGetPackageReferenceUpgrader) to upgrade your `packages.config` to `PackageReference` so that it will not store libs in every solution folders to eat up your disk space.

#### P.s.

NuGet take me nearly 10GB on my `C:\` .

[image: NuGet package cache folder]